# Pickle (Python 3.6) Writes Empty File

Tags: python, python-3.x, save, pickle

I'm trying to teach myself Python and so created a dumb script to check a blogging website to check for new updates and then save metadata associated to the updates. If there are new posts, I open the previous metadata, append the new metadata, and then save.  However, I find that quite often (can't figure out when it does and does not work), these updates produce an empty file, and I lose all the metadata.

```
if new_post_count > 0:
        file_name = 'all_posts' + user

        previous_posts = pickle.load(open(file_name, 'rb'))

        current_posts = get_posts(client, user, start_from_posts=0, total_posts=new_post_count)

        all_posts = previous_posts.extend(current_posts)

        f = open(file_name, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(all_posts, f)
        f.close()
```

Looking at the forums, it might make more sense to use something else to save my data besides pickle (any suggestions?). Even if that's the case, I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong here so I don't create the same mistake later.

Comment: don't pass `open(file_name, 'rb')` to `pickle.load`. Use a context manager to make sure the file is closed when you exit.

Comment: if your data is pure python dict/lists... you'd be better off with `json` that said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the pickle module but the line that reads:

```
 all_posts = previous_posts.extend(current_posts)
```

What actually happens is that the **extend** method is called, extending previous_posts in place, which once it has successfully completed returns the keyword **None**.

You then have this keyword being assigned to all_posts instead of the contents of previous_posts, and then it gets written to the file.

Try modifying it as follows:

```
if new_post_count > 0:
    file_name = 'all_posts' + user

    previous_posts = pickle.load(open(file_name, 'rb'))

    current_posts = get_posts(client, user, start_from_posts=0, total_posts=new_post_count)

    previous_posts.extend(current_posts)

    f = open(file_name, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(previous_posts, f)
    f.close()
```

Even better would be to include Jean-Francois' suggestion:

```
if new_post_count > 0:
    file_name = 'all_posts' + user
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
        previous_posts = pickle.load(f)

    current_posts = get_posts(client, user, start_from_posts=0, total_posts=new_post_count)

    previous_posts.extend(current_posts)

    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(previous_posts, f)
```

Comment: Interesting.  Is there a general philosophy on when these issues occur? I would have never expected 'None' to be returned from the extend operator.  Short of adding a line that says all_posts = previous_posts, is there a way to create a new list by simply combining the two?  And what do you mean by 'with' style?

Comment: @user71216 in this case you could do `all_posts = previous_posts + current_posts`

Comment: @user71216 note that the above method will only work as long as both are lists. If `current_posts` were a set instead, you would need to use the `extend()` method which works with any iterable

Comment: Have modified it taking on the suggested edit and removing the comment about the **with** style, as it is now incorporated. @user71216 it now automatically closes the opened file after each of the idented sections completes (this is the **with** style mentioned previously and now edited away).